# Different SCM for different profiles in Maven

Tags: maven, svn, version-control, maven-profiles

In my project we have to use maben-build-number plugin to construct the final name of the jar, for that purpose we use the revision of the SCN, so we need SCM

But we have two SVN on controlled environment without direct access and on our local test environment, so for our pouproses we have to use:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://dev.com/svn_repo/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://dev.com/svn_repo/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>http://dev.com/view.cvs</url>
</scm>
```

But for client env:

```
      <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://client.com/svn_repo/trunk</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://client.com/svn_repo/trunk</developerConnection>
        <url>http://client.com/view.cvs</url>
      </scm>
```

Is it possible to configure this in the different profiles. I tried

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>local</id>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://client.com/svn_repo/trunk</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://client.com/svn_repo/trunk</developerConnection>
        <url>http://client.com/view.cvs</url>
      </scm>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>remote</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://client.com/svn_repo/trunk</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://client.com/svn_repo/trunk</developerConnection>
        <url>http://client.com/view.cvs</url>
      </scm>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

But when I use the profile -Plocal, nothing happens?

Comment: The name of the artifact shouldn't be changed. Only some kind of information should be included to make it possible to identify the state of source code it was generated from. Furthermore i would build on one environment and deploy it other environments..So you don't need several SCM entries. Best would be to use a CI solution like Jenkins for such things..

Comment: OK. To understand that what I want is impossible in Maven?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a property for the SCM connection details I need to change for different profiles. Here is a summary of what I did.

Defined the property and it's default value the properties block.

```
<properties>
    <developerConnectionUrl><!-- developerConnection url here --></developerConnectionUrl>
</properties>
```

Set the scm block properties to use the global properties.

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>${developerConnectionUrl}</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Created a profile which changes the global property as required.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <developerConnectionUrl><!-- developerConnectionUrl url for profile --></developerConnectionUrl>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

As far as I know and from a quick scan of the schema the `scm` tag can only be used at the top level in the POM and is not valid inside the `profile` tag